# Why is $O(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^c}) = O(\int_1^\infty \frac{\log w}{w^c}dw)?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Let $1<c\le 2$. I have come across an equation that uses the fact that $O(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^c}) = O(\frac{1}{(c-1)^2}).$

I think the idea is to use that $O(\int_1^\infty \frac{\log w}{w^c})= O(\frac{1}{(c-1)^2})$, which I can show by splitting the integral into intervals less than or greter than $e^{\frac{1}{c-1}}$ and using that $1-c<0$.

My question is how do we know that the infinites series here and the infinite integral are of the same order?

Comment: $\frac{\log w}{w^c}$ is decreasing for $w > 100$ so $\sum_{n\ge 101} \frac{\log n}{n^c}\le \int_{100}^\infty \frac{\log w}{w^c}dw$

Comment: @reuns Right this is just the integral test nothing special.